# What is this kind of supply package called?

Tags: world-war-two, united-states

[image]

> 81 hundred pounds of ammunition, or other supplies.

The landing craft contains a package which the narrator describes as '81 hundred pounds of ammunition'. What is this kind of package called? It looks like it contains upwards of 200 smaller ammunition wooden crates. There's a tractor that pulls it out of the craft by a rope attached to the bottom of the package. The package is wrapped by some kind of cloth. As the package moves, it seems to not be solid because it doesn't retain a perfectly solid shape that I would expect from a big box, but I'm not sure. Is this just a strong cloth wrap around loose wooden crates? But if it's not solid, how does the tractor pull on it without breaking it apart? What is this called?

Source: [LCVP HIGGINS BOAT 1944 U.S. NAVY LANDING CRAFT TRAINING FILM 81614](https://youtu.be/osPQ8Kc3s48?t=152) (2 minutes 32 seconds)

Comment: "*What is this kind of supply package called?*": I'm not sure about your question, so I'll refrain from posting an answer, but it seems pretty obvious: this landing craft can carry soldiers, small vehicules, ammunition, and "*other supplies*". It's a boat that help resupply anything that's needed for the troups already on the shore/land. What's in the package doesn't really count here.

Comment: 2/2 and the package is always secured. Depending on the goods, it'll have some metallic/wooden frame if needed, plastic/cloth wrapping and so on... Navy/Air/Army are used to secure and transport goods, they're even the best of their kind IMO.

Comment: I'm sure there's a specific military desigation for this, but the ordinary English term is a "skid", because it's much longer than wide, unlike a pallet.

Comment: @Spencer: Alternatively, since it's wrapped, it might be referred to as either a *bale* or a *bundle*. I'd regard the distinction as being whether it's sitting on (and attached to) a frame separate from the material being shipped (thus being a pallet); or is providing its own structural integrity for shipping (and thus being a *bale* or *bundle*). Possibly other, or finer, linguistic distinctions could also be drawn.

Comment: I took everybody's input and rewatched the clip closely and I noticed that there seems to be a bit of visible light passing through the bottom of the package when it is coming off the craft. This makes me believe the package is indeed sitting on a pallet, or double pallet. And the way that the top of the package follows the bottom makes me think that there is metal straps that goes under the pallet and over the ammo boxes, holding them tight in place. Although I'm not sure if these are wooden boxes or straight ammo metal cans.

Comment: I’d call it a canvas bag? Maybe there was an official name eventually, but likely started as a kludge…